# Convert internal type to generic name/value pairs in c# without using reflection

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I had previousily posted a question on this forum - 'to convert an internal type to a list of generic name/value pairs'. I did recieve some great answers, which pointed me in the direction of using reflection, I did a brief proof of concept and it looked good. However there has been some questions around the use of reflection, in terms of performance etc. I am wondering is there any other ways of doing this?

See the outline of the requirement below:

We just want to take an internal type, check if the field exists in a enum or list, and if its populated move it into a generic name/value pair list. This is so we can send out a lot of information in a general/standard way without worrying about changing schemas etc. if a new field is added. My issue is how to populate the generic structure.

```
[Serializable]
public class Location
    {   
          public string sAddress { get; set; }
          public string sCity { get; set; }
          public int iZipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Needs to be transformed into:

```
<AttributeList>
  <Attribute>
    <Name>sAddress</Name>
    <Value>123 ABC Street</Value>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
  </Attribute>
</AttributeList>
```

Repeat for sCity and iZipCode. Only way I can think of (without using reflection) is to manually code for each field on the internal structure - bit seems very ineffecticent to me

Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you measured and detected a performance issue?

Answer (score 3):

Reflection doesn't have to be terribly inefficient. If you know you're going to execute basically the same code over and over again, you can create delegates from the reflection-based members. Those will execute *much* quicker. See [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) for various options (remembering that a property is basically just a get/set method pair).

If you're using .NET 3.5, you could use expression trees as a slight alternative approach to building the delegates.

Once you've got the delegate-based form, performance should be pretty reasonable.

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't sleep, he waits.